# Django saving uploaded .doc files as .zip files?

Tags: python, django, file, upload, docx

So I used the standard uploading-file code to make an upload feature onto my site. All the file types I have tested (pdf, gif, jpg) seem to work fine, but when I try to upload a docx file, Django stores the file as a .zip file. Apparently it's something to do with "content sniffing"? Here's the code -

```
def upload_form(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':

    # Gets the information about the file
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
    file_size, file_name = uploaded_file.size, "ID" + str(File.objects.all().count()) + "%" + request.POST['name']

    # Stops the processing if the file size is too large
    if(file_size > 5242880):
      return render_to_response('upload_form.html', { 'large_file' : '1' }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    file_path, file_course = '/home/simon/Centum/static/notes/' + file_name, request.POST['course']

    # Reads and writes the chunks
    with open(file_path, 'wb+') as destination:
      for chunk in request.FILES['file'].chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)     

    # Saves the file
    upload = File(
      name = file_name,
      real_name = file_name[file_name.find('%') + 1:],
      user = request.user,
      path = file_path,
      size = int(file_size),
      course = file_course.upper(),
      date_uploaded = datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    upload.save()
    return render_to_response('upload_form.html', {'success' : '1'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Anyway to make it stay as a .docx upon upload?

Comment: This isn't so unexpected, since docx/xlsx/... files (and their LibreOffice counterparts) are just zip files containing (mostly) XML data.

Comment: Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

A docx file *is* a zip file. It doesn't matter if django is saving it with a zip extension, that doesn't alter the content, and you could serve it up with any filename you like. What is the actual problem you are facing?